# How can I get an array of ImageDraw object?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm writing a generic algorithm for the pictures so I started with Image class of PIL library and created a numpy array of input image. So now I want to draw some figures and the easiest way is to use ImageDraw, but then again I should use arrays for the next evolution so I need to convert ImageDraw object either to the Image object or to a numpy array.

Any suggestions how can I do that?

I tried to use a numpy conversion which worked on the Image objects. Tried to find included methods of conversion

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy

input_image = Image.open("i2.jpg")
width, height = input_image.size
num_weights = width * height

image_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(Image.new('RGB', (width, height), 'WHITE'))
input_image = numpy.array(input_image.getdata())

#Do some staff with image_draw using information from input_image
#And try to convert image_draw to input_image
```

I want to have as the output a numpy array or Image object

Comment: Sorry, I've read all the words but I have no idea what you want to do. Why do you think you need an array of anything?

Comment: I wanted to use an evolutionary algorithm for art drawing. Because EA uses takes millions of iterations I wanted to use fast numpy arrays for it instead of using ImageDraws

Comment: @MarkSetchell, also, the reason isn't important, this is just a general question that can apply to a lot of things. I am writing neural inpainting deep disentangled variational autoencoders (if that means anything to you), and this applies to me too.

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to process an image both as a `PIL Image` so you can draw on it, and also as a Numpy array so you can do processing on it.

So, here is an example of how to draw on an image with PIL, then convert it to a Numpy array and do some processing on it, then convert it back to a PIL Image.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Create a black 600x200 image
img = Image.new('RGB', (600, 200))

# Get a drawing handle
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

# Draw on image
draw.rectangle(xy=[10,20,300,80], fill='red')

# Save as "result1.png"
img.save('result1.png')

# Convert PIL Image to Numpy array for processing
na = np.array(img)

# Make mask selecting red pixels then make them blue
Rmask =(na[:, :, 0:3] == [255,0,0]).all(2) 
na[Rmask] = [0,0,255]

# Convert Numpy array back to PIL Image
img = Image.fromarray(na)

# Save as "result2.png"
img.save('result2.png')
```

The two images are `"result1.png"`:

[image]

and `"result2.png"`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood it but didn't write an answer =) But I'm not sure about effectiveness of this solution, because it takes a lot of conversions

Comment: Maybe if you could describe how you generate the next evolution, we could work out how to do it fast...

Comment: Firstly I do fitness, it checks how the population fits on the original image, for now it's just the difference of RGB, then I'm taking half of best fit population to make parents from them. Then I'm drawing circles on the best fit pixels and making other pixels mixing. Exactly this step takes a lot of time, because for every picture in population I'm firstly creating an empty image, then make some drawings on them, convert this image into an array and add this values to the initial population.

Comment: Sounds like it would benefit from multithreading and being written in C/C++ to me!